# How do I enable logging for each REST call to my API?

Tags: rest, api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to test out my API in WSO2 API Manager. I've gone to the API Store, logged in as a regular client user, subscribed to the API, and now I'm trying to test it using the API Console. I can see the API just fine, and I'm clicking the "try it out" button. Unfortunately, for all of my API calls, I just get the progress meter going on forever (the "....." thing on the right). It never completes.

There is nothing in the logs that indicates what is going wrong. I have tried turning a ton of different settings in the log4j.properties file to TRACE or DEBUG, and I'm still getting nothing.

I think I'm asking something very basic, but there seems to be no information about it anywhere: How do I just get the product to log when a REST message comes in to the gateway, and log the HTTP it is trying to send to **my** REST API? I'm sure if I could get that showing in a log, then I could probably figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: You can enable wire logs to check your request as mentioned in [1]. Please do restart the server when you are enabling.
[1] - 
http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/09/wso2-esb-all-about-wire-logs.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it in [API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) (hosted version of API Manager): http://wso2.com/blogs/cloud/trace-api-calls-and-responses/ - I assume that the same mediation sequences are in the latest version of the product too.

[image]